# Can I say "It's right answer" instead of "It's correct answer"?

Tags: sentence-structure

In the context of proper answering on question, what is more suitable or acceptable?

> 1. It's correct answer!
> 2. It's right answer!

Comment: Neither is acceptable to native speakers - but if you include the required definite article, *It's **the** correct/right answer* is perfectly valid regardless of which adjective you use (and in this context, there's no difference in meaning between *correct* and *right*, so you can use whichever you like).

Comment: @FumbleFingers That would stand just fine as an answer so I'm not sure why you posted it as a comment.

Comment: @David Richerby: Because offhand I don't know how to explain to OP why the article is *required* in the given context. And more specifically I'm not sure whether there's any justification for my feeling that an *indefinite* article is acceptable with *It's **a** correct answer* (in some contexts), but that doesn't seem to work so well with *It's a **right** answer*. I don't see much point in answers that just say *this is right and that's wrong*, if they don't provide a reason (and I kinda doubt this one is just "idiomatic preference").

Comment: @fumble I think you are vastly overthinking things. Just post the answer. Vacillating about tangential minutiae and posting weasel answers in comments isn't terribly helpful.

Comment: @Esoteric: I don't get *paid* to contribute to ELL, and I don't for one moment suppose there's a shortage of users able and willing to post the substance of my first comment as an answer. I've no idea whether your "weasel" applies to my first comment answering OP, or the second answering *you* - but whichever it is, obviously I reject the accusation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Correct* sounds a little more formal to me, but the choice is purely one of personal or stylistic preference. Both are equally acceptable, provided that you place an article (either *the* or *a*) before *answer*.

Which article you use depends on the context. Are there multiple, equally correct answers, and is mentioning them relevant? If so, use *a*. If there's only one possible answer under consideration, use *the*. If you really have no idea which one to pick, *the* is more likely to be correct, because we more often use the sentence in question when discussing questions which only have one right answer.

An example: Suppose you are a contestant in a trivia game. Typically in such games each question has only one correct answer. You answer a question. Host: "I'm sorry, that's not *the* right answer." A few minutes later, they issue a correction: "It turns out that was *a* correct answer, so we have awarded you the points."