# Is there any difference between "right" or "correct" for confirmation?

Tags: difference

The question revolves around 'right?' at the end added when the speaker is not sure about her/his understanding.

I think it is common to use "..., right?" where "..." is the speaker's understanding (of the topic under discussion) while it is possible to use *correct* in the same way.

Do *right* and *correct* make the sentence(s) sound different in formality or implied attitudes of the speaker?

A related question is about *right/correct* for answering. Does it make any difference just to say "(That is) Correct." or "(That is/That's) Right." as a response to a "..., right?" statement?

---

Related questions:

- [Is “right English” correct?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/120250/140111)
- [Can I say "It's right answer" instead of "It's correct answer"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/56942/140111)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both **..., right?** and **..., correct?** are *laconic*. The first is *informal* and, to my ageing UK ears, American, though it's widely used here now. The second is less colloquial and is somewhat brusque: like an army officer questioning his men. If instead you were to ask, in a new sentence, "Is that right/correct?" it would be colloquial, less brusque and - with "correct" - more *formal*.

Alternatively, and with **unimpeachable grammar**,  we might seek confirmation by asking, "aren't you?" or "didn't it?" or "haven't they?" or whatever is appropriate. For example:

> You're Jones, aren't you?
> It rained, didn't it?
> They've lost
> the game, haven't they?

On your related question, the standard informal responses to the informal **..., right?** are "Yeah", "Yes", "Right" and (a little more formally) "That's right". Saying "(That is) correct" might be perceived as [snooty](https://www.lexico.com/definition/snooty): your formality drawing attention to his/her informality.